# Listing timestamp month/year as blog archive in PHP

Tags: php, unix-timestamp

Assuming I have multiple timestamps of multiple years and months in an array of timestamps (eg 123456, 111222333, 2112321321, 232234422, 1111343222, 231111211, etc), I want to sort them into this format:

```
2012
    06
    09

2004
    03
    08

2003
    01
    02
```

Is there any way of doing this? I am using PHP

Comment: Yes.  There is probably several dozen ways of doing it.  What have you tried?

Comment: Just a tip: [sort](http://www.php.net/sort) and [date()](http://www.php.net/date) might just prove an informative couple of pages to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution:

```
foreach($timestamps as $time){
    $year = date('Y', $time);
    $month = date('m', $time);
    if(!$ts_arr[$year]){
        $ts_arr[$year] = array();
    }
    array_push($ts_arr[$year], $month);
    $ts_arr[$year] = array_unique($ts_arr[$year]);
}
```

It's not perfect, but it works!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this.

See if this gets you started; it's incomplete but takes care of most of it.  Just a few additions and it should work how you want.

```
<?php

$timestamps = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < 100; ++$i) {
    $ts = mktime(rand(0, 23), rand(0, 59), rand(0, 59), rand(1, 12), rand(1, 31), rand(2000, 2012));

    $timestamps[] = $ts;
}

sort($timestamps);

$lastYear = null;

echo "<ul>\n";

foreach($timestamps as $ts) {
    $year = date('Y', $ts);

    if ($year != $lastYear) {
        if ($lastYear != null) {
            echo "</ul>\n";
        }

        $lastYear = $year;

        echo "<li>$year<ul>\n";
    }

    echo "<li>" . date('m-d', $ts) . "</li>\n";
}

echo "</ul></ul>";
```

I create an array of 100 random timestamps to populate the list at the beginning.